# Как соединить две ячейки Python GUI(Tkinter)

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, grid

Мне нужно вложить свою кнопку в таблицу, но одной ячейки мен мало и мне нужно объединить две ячейки. Как это сделать с помощью grid().[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно что б моя кнопка заняла две ячейки снизу 12 и 15. Вот код:

```
class Gui:

    def __init__(self):
        self.initWin()
        self.initNumbButtons()
        self.key.mainloop()
    pass

    def initWin(self):
        self.key = Tk()
        self.number_frame = Frame(self.key, bg = "#04B404")
        self.other_frame = Frame(self.key, bg = "#04B404")
    pass

    def initNumbButtons(self):
        font_style = font.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=0, weight="bold")
        temp = Button(self.key, text="0", width=5, height=2, bg="green", bd=0, command=lambda:self.setBet(0), font=font_style, fg="white")
        temp.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        count = 0

        for x in range(1,13):
            for y in range(1,4):
                count = count + 1
                if (x+y)%2==0:

                    temp = Button(self.key,
                              width=5,
                              height=2,
                              bg="red",
                              text="{}".format(count),
                              command = lambda o=count: self.setBet(o),
                              font = font_style,
                              fg = "white",
                              bd=0)

                    temp.grid(row=y, column=1+x, sticky=N+S+E+W)
                else:
                    temp = Button(self.key,
                              width=5,
                              height=2,
                              bg="black",
                              text="{}".format(count),
                              command = lambda o=count: self.setBet(o),
                              font=font_style,
                              fg = "white",
                              bd=0)

                    temp.grid(row=y, column=1 + x, sticky=N + S + E + W)
    pass


    def initOtherButton(self):
        temp = Button(self.key, width=5, height=2, bg="green", bd=0, command=lambda: self.setBet(0))
        temp.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=N + S + E + W)
        temp = Button(self.key, width=5, height=2, bg="green", bd=0, command=lambda: self.setBet(0))
        temp.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=N + S + E + W)

    pass


    def setBet(self, x):
        self.bet = x
        print(self.bet)
    pass

obj = Gui()
```

Comment: Решено. С использованием параметра `columnspan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grid` Этот упаковщик представляет собой таблицу с ячейками, в которые помещаются виджеты.

**Аргументы**:

- rowspan - сколько строк занимает виджет
- columnspan - сколько столбцов    занимает виджет.

**Пример**:

```
entry1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)
```